# How to display image after selecting path in FileUpload controller without clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload

Recently I have been developing web form application in ASP.NET (c#):
I have an Image control:

```
<asp:Image ID="Avatar" runat="server" Height="225px" ImageUrl="~/Images/NoUser.jpg" Width="225px" />
```

And FileUpload & Button control

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="avatarUpload" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload" />
```

When user click button then "Upload" code is executed (the image is sent to the database). Problem is that I like to display the image which the user selected in Avatar Image controller before the user clicks "desperate" button.

Is that possible to do this automatically?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With the help of `File Api` of `HTML5` ([Example: Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)) you can accomplish this easily. Change the markup to use `input type="file"` instead of `asp:FileUpload` and add ID, add tag `runat="server"` to make it accessible from server. Your markup should look like:

```
<input ID="avatarUpload" type="file" name="file" onchange="previewFile()"  runat="server" />
<%--<asp:FileUpload ID="avatarUpload" runat="server" />--%>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload" />
<asp:Image ID="Avatar" runat="server" Height="225px" ImageUrl="~/Images/NoUser.jpg" Width="225px" />
```

Now add a javascript function `previewFile` in the head of document:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function previewFile() {
            var preview = document.querySelector('#<%=Avatar.ClientID %>');
            var file = document.querySelector('#<%=avatarUpload.ClientID %>').files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function () {
                preview.src = reader.result;
            }

            if (file) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                preview.src = "";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Now after selecting an image you can see the preview like below:
[image]

You can use css to re-size it to a thumbnail. 
After clicking the Upload button, in the code you can find the posted file:

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int contentLength = avatarUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;//You may need it for validation
    string contentType = avatarUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;//You may need it for validation
    string fileName = avatarUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
    avatarUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"c:\test.tmp");//Or code to save in the DataBase.
}
```

Comment: Any ideas why I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#<%=Avatar.ClientID %>' is not a valid selector.` error?