# How to upload Image Automatically After Selecting File in a Gridview each row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview that has a FileUpload in each row.  When you click on file upload, it selects the file and then i click upload on a button that is in the gridview row as well.

I want to eliminate the clicking Upload button and just automatically upload the file after browsing for it.

How would I do this??

here is my gridview and code I run currently:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvParts" runat="server" class="table table-bordered table-highlight" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                      <Columns>
                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                              <ItemTemplate>
                                  <center><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/imageicon.png" CommandName="View" Visible="False" /></center>
                                             <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="104px" />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex  %>'
                            Text="Upload" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                              </ItemTemplate>
                              <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                          </asp:TemplateField>
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="PART_ID" HeaderText="Part ID" SortExpression="PART_ID" />
                          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Has Image" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="PART_NUMBER" HeaderText="Part Number" SortExpression="PART_NUMBER" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="DESCRIPTION" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIPTION2" HeaderText="Description 2" SortExpression="DESCRIPTION2" />
                      </Columns>
                  </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my code to execute after click the Upload button(Which I am trying to eliminate, so I just have to choose the file and it automatically uploads)

```
   Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gvParts.Rows
            Dim file As FileUpload = CType(row.FindControl("FileUpload1"), FileUpload)
            If (Not (file) Is Nothing) Then
                If file.HasFile Then

                    ' Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
                    Dim filePath As String = file.PostedFile.FileName
                    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
                    Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(filename)
                    Dim contenttype As String = String.Empty

                    'Set the contenttype based on File Extension
                    Select Case ext
                        Case ".jpg"
                            contenttype = "image/jpg"
                            Exit Select
                        Case ".png"
                            contenttype = "image/png"
                            Exit Select
                        Case ".gif"
                            contenttype = "image/gif"
                            Exit Select
                    End Select
                    If contenttype <> String.Empty Then
                        Dim fs As Stream = file.PostedFile.InputStream
                        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
                        Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)

                        'insert the file into database
                        Dim strQuery As String = "insert into tbl_TMGPartImages (PartID, ImageName, ContentType, Data) values (@PartID, @ImageName, @ContentType, @Data)"
                        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartID", row.Cells(1).Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImageName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value _
                        = contenttype
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes

                        Try
                            Dim con8 As SqlClient.SqlConnection
                            Dim cmd8 As SqlClient.SqlCommand
                            con8 = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MainConnectionString").ToString)
                            con8.Open()
                            cmd8 = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
                            cmd8 = New SqlCommand("Delete from [TMGGoods].[dbo].[tbl_TMGPartImages] where PartID = @PartID", con8)
                            cmd8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartID", row.Cells(1).Text)
                            cmd8.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            con8.Close()

                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try

                        InsertUpdateData(cmd)

                    Else

                    End If


                End If

            End If

        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: if you want to view it before upload check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319270/how-to-display-image-after-selecting-path-in-fileupload-controller-without-click

Comment: @Abdul This is not what I'm trying to do.